# PHP reordering array

Tags: php, math, logic

I've got an array per default:

```
array( 1=>1,2 =>2, 3=>3, 4=>4, 5=>5, 6=>6, 7=>7, 8=>8, 9=>9 )
```

Now an operation is possible to change the numbers for example into:

```
array( 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>3, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>6, 7=>7, 8=>8, 9=>9 )
--> changed the value of key 1, 2, 4 and 5
```

After this I need the following result

```
array( 1=>1, 2=1, 3=>2, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>3, 7=>4, 8=>5, 9=>6  )
--> changed the value of key 3, 6, 7, 8, 9 in the right order that no number is missing like the operation has done above.
```

Its a grid 3x3. Position 1 is 1, Position 2 is 2 and so on. Now a database could set that Position 1, 2, 4, 5 are the same and threated as 1. So the database sends: 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9. Now the field from place 3 is 3, but should be the field from 2. Also the field from 6 must now be field 3 and so on.

Note: The operation is able to change every value in the array. for example the value of the 
keys 4, 5, 7, 8

How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: [Here you have the answer for most simple PHP questions, the PHP.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Also, why don't you google "array php"?

Comment: are you giving us one question from IQ test? :D like find the next element in series? :)

Comment: Not really, I'm really stuck. Its not only a sort array thing.

Comment: i dont get your logic. How do you mean that no number is missing? When you want to change array element, you access it with $array_name[$i] with $i being position in array (0 is first).

Comment: The value of the keys must be ascending and are not allowed to miss a number. Do you know what i mean? E.g. Key 3 has the value 3. But value 2 is missing, so set key 3 = 2 and so on.

Comment: I don't see any dependency between the three arrays, why in the last one there is 1=>1 and 2=>1? and 3=2 but you haven't changed 3=>3?

Comment: The last array is what I need. The second array is what I get. The difference is that there are numbers missing. value of key 3 must be 2 and not 3, because 2 is now 1.

Comment: No, it mustn't. It might be even 1000. Or explain WHY it must. I know that the third array comes from some combination of the previous two, but I can't figure what should be done, so I can't help you.

Comment: But I need it like that :O

Comment: Is this something like magic square or sudoku?

Comment: Its a grid 3x3. Position 1 is 1, Position 2 is 2 and so on. Now a database could set that Position 1, 2, 4, 5 are the same and threated as 1. So the database sends: 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9. 
Now the field from place 3 is 3, but should be the field from 2. Also the field from 6 must now be field 3 and so on.

Comment: Why haven't you written this in the question? All right then, what have you tried?

Comment: loop through array and check if value of key is one less then the next array keys value. If not make so... but then the 1, 1 getting to 1, 2 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable, in which you will store the max number. If you then iterate, check if the number from the array is lower then max, and if it is, then you do nothing, and if it is larger than max, so you put it in the third array and increase max.

```
$max = 0; // maximum value
$array3 = array(); // output array

foreach($array2 as $key=>$element){ // iterate for all elements
  if($array2[$key] > $max){
    $max++;
    $array3[$key] = $max;
    }
  else
    $array3[$key]=1; // *
} // end foreach
```

In the line marked with `// *` it puts 1 everytime. You may need to search if the value was once before, because it does not need to be always 1. You may use for example something like `array_search`.

Comment: I can't explain it better. You can add some lines with `var_dump`s in each line to see what happens with variables.